# Insertions with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an unsorted list of ints:

```
1 3 1 2 4 3 2 1
```

I need to sort it, and before each group of equal numbers, insert a 0:

```
0 1 1 1 0 2 2 0 3 3 0 4
```

Is there a way to get from the first list to the second list with just one LINQ statement? I'm stuck at

```
from num in numbers
orderby num
select num
```

followed by a foreach loop that manually constructs the final output based on these results. I'd like to eliminate the second loop entirely, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
list.GroupBy(n => n)
      .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
      .SelectMany(g => new[] { 0 }.Concat(g))
```

For each group of numbers, prepend 0, and then flatten the list with `SelectMany`.

And in query syntax:

```
from num in list
group num by num into groupOfNums
orderby groupOfNums.Key
from n in new[] { 0 }.Concat(groupOfNums)
select n
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] nums = { 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3 ,2 ,1};
var newlist = nums.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                  .SelectMany(g => new[] { 0 }.Concat(g)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out on LinqPad.

```
var list = new int[]{1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1};
var q = from x in list
        orderby x
        group x by x into xs
        from y in (new int[]{0}).Concat(xs)
        select y;
q.Dump();
```

This should give you the desired result.